# Ошибка PageSpeed Insights: Тайм-аут при получении основного ресурса

Tags: оптимизация-сайтов, pagespeed-insights

Оптимизировал сайт, следуя рекомендациям Google, добился показателя 94/96 в PageSpeed Insights. Но сейчас, когда пробую проверить сайт через этот сервис, выдается ошибка: "Тайм-аут при получении основного ресурса. Убедитесь, что страница загружается в браузере, и повторите попытку". Другие сервисы, оценивающие скорость сайта, не ругаются, например, GTmetrix - 93%, а pingdom - 88.

В чем может быть причина?

**PS**: статический сайт на html.
Ссылки:
[PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=lookatbg.com) |
[GTmetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/lookatbg.com/GKEXCr7q)

Comment: Детали, пожалуйста: линк веб-сайта, линк тестирования вашего веб-сайта с PageSpeed Insights, линки GTmetrix, а pingdom.

Comment: Ссылки:
[PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=lookatbg.com) |

[GTmetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/lookatbg.com/GKEXCr7q) |

[pingdom](https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/eoYFXr/https://lookatbg.com)

PS сайт на обычном html

Comment: Действительно имеется какая-то ошибка навигации, смотрите этот тест скорости загрузки http://www.webpagetest.org/result/171022_2N_125ea64da5c311a5813875ebee94832f/ . Обратитесь к вашему хостингу.